# f2py: Could not locate executable C:Python27pythonw.exe Executable C:Python27pythonw.exe does not exist

Tags: python, numpy, fortran, f2py

I am trying to run a simple Fortran subroutine using `numpy.f2py` as described on: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/c-info.python-as-glue.html#calling-f2py-from-python

When I try to compile (`f2py.compile(source, modulename='add')`) from python I get the following error:

```
"Could not locate executable C:Python27pythonw.exe
Executable C:Python27pythonw.exe does not exist"
```

Looking for this file I found that `C:\Python27\pythonw.exe` does exist in my system, so could it possible be a problem with the path?

In any case, any advice on how to make my code work?

Comment: The error message doesn't have slashes. Perhaps it's looking in directory "C:" for an executable named "Python27pythonw"?

Comment: Yes, I think it is.. but what can I do about it?

Comment: I upvoted the question, because I am having the exact same problem. Somehow f2py gets a bad executable name or loses the double slashes in the process. I had a look at the source code, but I was not able to determine where it comes from. I guess the problem must lie somewhere in the __init__.py file from f2py. The weird thing is that calling f2py from the command line does work. PS: same code works on ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

I found a quick fix for the problem. However, I cannot guarantee that nothing else will break when using this.

In the file:

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\__init__.py
```

in line 40, change

```
s,o = exec_command(c)
```

to

```
s = os.system(c)
```

It seems that the main error lies in numpy.distutils.exec_command, which seems to omit the backslashes when calling python. Again, I may be playing with forces I do not understand, by replacing the more involved exec_command by os.system call. But it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach without "losing" `o` (`output`) in `s = os.system(c)` is to implement

```
c = c.replace("\\", "\\\\")
```

before `s,o = exec_command(c)` or `status, output = exec_command(c)`.